# Angular if condition from value of ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I'm rendering data in a table using Angular and ng-repeat. What I would like to do is add an if condition to say if the value contained in ng-repeat is a certain word, set the background colour of that row to red. I think it might look something like this, but I'm not sure how to do this in Angular.

```
if( {{field.value}} == THING){
var backgroundColour = red;
}
```

I was thinking of using ng-filter, although I dont wan't to actually filter the data, just set a variable based  on a value.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add an `ng-class` in the html to achieve this.

```
<div ng-repeat"field in fields" ng-class="{'with-background': field.value == THING}">
    {{field.value}}
</div>
```

And then add `with-background` to css

```
.with-background {
    background-color: red;
}
```

If THING is a variable pointing to some other value, you don't have to use quotes and if it's meant to be a string, use it as `'THING'`

Here's the official documentation of ngClass: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Comment: Thanks, so I'm pulling field.value from ng-repeat, so when I use it in my table I use {{field.value}}. To use your example should I use {{field.value}} == THING, or just field.value without the {{}}? Also, should THING be quoted?

Comment: you don't have to use `{{}}` and I don't know what thing is, if it's a variable, don't use `' '` and if it's meant to be a string, use the quotes.

Comment: Thanks, I was using double quotes for the field.value == "THING" when I should have been using single quotes! I changed to field.value == 'THING' and It's working now!

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this below:

```
<div ng-repeat="field in collections" 
         ng-if="field.value && field.value =='THING'">
      {{backgroundcolor}}
</div>
```

Or you could you use ng-class directive

```
<div id="wrap" ng-class="{true: 'yourClassName'}[field.value]">
```

Answer (score 1):

You cann also use ng-style for this

```
<div ng-style="field.value == THING?{'background-color':'red'}:{}">
    Hello Plunker!
</div>
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4njoOrgAoN4p3AdOhEaI?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-class directive

```
<tr ng-class="{'color-red': item.value > 0}" ng-repeat="item in vm.items">
    <td>{{ item.value }}>/td>
</tr>
```